# RegexKitLite & Unrecognized Selector Sent to Instance Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, instance

I am not sure why the following line:

```
addDetails.Address = [addDetails.Address stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:@" +" withString:@" "];
```

causes an "Unrecognized Selector Sent to Instance" error, closing my iPhone App in my Simulator(XCode).

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: How is Address declared?

Comment: Please add code describing the Address property or method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:withString: is a NSString category defined in RegexKitLite.h of RegexKitLite lib. 
Looks like you haven't add this category into your project properly see:
http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/#AddingRegexKitLitetoyourProject
or addDetails.Address is not NSString.

Comment: Oh Yes! That solved the problem!
The problem was with the way the libraries were added. I had simply just added the 'RegexKitLite.h' file without getting the dynamic library in. Thanks Vladimir!